# Apply webpack loader only for a specific entry bundle

Tags: webpack, bundle, config, code-splitting

Is it possible to apply a specific loader only for modules bundled within a specific entry bundle

my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: path.resolve(cwd, 'src', 'index.ts'),
    tests =[...glob.sync('**/*.spec.ts')],
    polyfills: ['polyfill1', 'polyfill2'],
  },
  output: {
    library: pkg.name,
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: '[name].js',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    path: path.resolve(cwd, 'build'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', 'mjs']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(t|j)s/, // this loader should only be used for every file that is bundled in entrypoint 'tests'
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        ...options
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.(t|j)s/, // this loader should only be used for every file that is bundled in entrypoint 'bundle'
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        ...options
      }
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to run a specific loader only for files in a specific entry bundle, in the webpack docs I did not find any clue on how to query the bundle name in which the file is used, I could only access the filename of the file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use inline loader syntax in entry points to make this work (tested in Webpack 4.42.1)

The following `webpack.config.js` will apply `raw-loader` to `script.js` for the `script_raw` entry point but not for the `script_plain` entry point.

```js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
      'script_raw': 'raw-loader!./script.js',
      'script_plain': './script.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: '/app/out',
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
};
```

You can pass different options with the query string (`?name=value`) syntax